# Spring Boot Unit Testing MockMvc Null Body

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, mockmvc

I am having dificulties with using MockMvc.
Here I have simple Service and controller classes:

Service:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class EmployeeService {
    //...

    public Employee GetSample() {
    //...
    //filling Employee Entities
    return new Employee(
            "Harriet"
            , "random"
            , 25);
    }
}
```

controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/info")
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Validated
public class EmployeeController {
    private final EmployeeService employeeService;

    @PostMapping("/GetEmployee")
    public ResponseEntity<Employee> GetEmployee() {
       Employee employee = employeeService.GetSample();
       return new ResponseEntity<>(employee, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Test:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EmployeeTestCase {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @InjectMocks
    private EmployeeController EmployeeController;

    @Mock
    private EmployeeService employeeService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(employeeController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getEmployee() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/info/GetEmployee")).andDo(print());
    }
}
```

**when I try to use MockMvc I get null body. It seems employee is null. But I didn't understand why.**
I thought that when test uses `perform`, it should initialise employee and later on it should't be null.
I tried to cut the code as much as possible. I hope it is not long.

Note : also tried to use `Mockito.when(employeeController.GetEmployee()).thenCallRealMethod();`

Comment: Why is GetEmployee POST?

Comment: It will be used as a post function later on this program. But even if I make it get, problem is the same.

Comment: and you are sure that GetSample return not null?

Comment: Replace `@InjectMocks` with `@Autowired` and `@Mock` with `@MockBean` (if you want to provide a mocked service response).

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes I think it shouldn't. I tried it with toString method.

Comment: @slauth I tried that :) Same response

Comment: You'd need to provide a mocked response additionally… just delete the `@MockBean` part to begin with.

Comment: @slauth you mean in setUp I need something like :
thenReturn(someResponse) ?

Comment: If using `@MockBean` then yes, you'd need to provide a response (mocks return `null` by default). But better start simple and delete the `@MockBean` part. Your real `EmployeeService` will be used in this case.

Comment: If you must use @MockBean, take a look at https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-mockbean-annotation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The @SpringBootTest annotation loads the complete Spring application
> context.  That means you do not mock your layers
> (Services/Controllers).

If you wanted to test specific layers of your application, you could look into test slice annotations offered by `Springboot`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/test-auto-configuration.html

In contrast, a `test slice` annotation only loads beans required to test a particular layer. And because of this, we can avoid unnecessary mocking and side effects.

An example of a Test Slice is `@WebMvcTest`

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HelloController.class,
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = SecurityConfig.class)
        }
)
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;


    @Test
    public void hello() throws Exception {
        String hello = "hello";

        mvc.perform(get("/hello"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(hello));
    }


    @Test
    public void helloDto() throws Exception {
        String name = "hello";
        int amount = 1000;

        mvc.perform(
                        get("/hello/dto")
                                .param("name", name)
                                .param("amount", String.valueOf(amount)))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(name)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.amount", is(amount)));
    }
}
```

---

However if you really wanted to load up the SpringBoot Application context, say for an Integration Test, then you have a few options:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class TestingWebApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Hello, World")));
    }
}
```

---

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AuctionControllerIntTest {

    @Autowired
    AuctionController controller;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("setup()...");
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void create_ValidAuction_ShouldAddNewAuction() throws Exception {
        final Auction auction = new Auction(
                "Standing Desk",
                "Stand up desk to help you stretch your legs during the day.",
                "Johnnie34",
                350.00);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/auctions")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(toJson(auction)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }
}
```

---

Lets say you don't want to load up any layers at all, and you want to mock everything, such as for example a Unit Test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class DemoApplicationTest {

    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private Demo noneAutoWiredDemoInstance;

    @Test
    public void testConstructorCreation() {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(userRepository.count()).thenReturn(0L);

        noneAutoWiredDemoInstance = new Demo(userRepository);

        Assertions.assertEquals("Count: 0", noneAutoWiredDemoInstance.toString());
    }
}
```